# SQL, Order By - How to give more authority to other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM converts 
WHERE email='myemail@googlemail.com' AND status!='1' 
ORDER BY date ASC, priority DESC
```

This just orders by date but I want to give my column "priority" more authority. How can I do this?

It should order by date first but if the time between two records is 10 mintues then I want priority to take over. How can I do this in my SQL statement or does this have to be in my application logic? I was hoping I could do it in my SQL statement.

Thank you all for any help

Comment: I don't think the requirements are well defined. Consider the following entries:

a) 0:0  1
b) 0:7  2
c) 0:14 3

From the requirements it follows that: b) should come before a) and c) before b) but a) should come before c). This isn't possible with the usual definitions of 'before'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could quantize the 'date' ordering into 10 minute chunks, so how about ordering by floor(unix_timestamp(date)/600), and then by priority

```
SELECT * FROM converts 
WHERE email='myemail@googlemail.com' AND status!='1' 
ORDER BY floor(unix_timestamp(date)/600) ASC, priority DESC
```

Though two dates can be still be less than 10 mins apart but straddle two different 10 minute "chunks". Maybe that is sufficient, but I think to do exactly what you request is better done by the application.

*(OP requested expanded explanation....)*

Take two times which straddle a ten minute boundary, like 9:09 and 9:11 today:

- floor(unix_timestamp('2009-03-16 09:**09**:00')/600)  = 2061990
- floor(unix_timestamp('2009-03-16 09:**11**:00')/600)  = 2061991

Suppose you had a higher priority row for 09:11 than 09:09 - it will still appear *after* the 09:09 row because it fell into the next 10 minute chunk, even though it was only 2 minutes different.

So this approach is an approximation, but doesn't solve the problem as originally stated.

The way you stated your problem, a high priority row could appear before one recorded several hours (or days, or months!) earlier, as long there was an unbroken series of lower priority row with an interval less than 10 minutes.

Comment: OMG, your so awesome! I just executed that query and its exactly the output I needed! I also checked when several dates are within 10 minutes of each and the priority column took over correctly. Can you explain why you thought it wasn't sufficient please Paul :)

Comment: I have expanded the answer to explain

Answer (score 1):

Another variation would be:

```
SELECT * FROM converts 
WHERE email='myemail@googlemail.com' AND status!='1' 
ORDER BY (unix_timestamp(date)/60) - priority
```

Still not exactly what you required, but pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really meant "time between two records is 10 mintues [or less] then I want priority to take over?

then just sort by ten minutes blocks, and then by priority...

Select ...
Order By DateDiff(min, 0, Date) / 10, Priority

you can adjust the 0 value to control where each "tem-minute-block" starts and stops... 
If MySql does not have a DateDiff function, use whatever expression in MySQL that provides a count of minutes since some reference time...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 / 2008, the you can accomplish this task with a recursive CTE.  Please note I wrote this text in notepad and it hasn't been tested yet.  Once I have a chance to test the query results, then I will update the CTE if there is an error or remove this comment altogether.

WITH date_cte

AS

```
(SELECT *
    , 'sequential_order' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (PARTITION BY email
        ORDER BY date ASC, priority DESC)
FROM converts
WHERE email = 'myemail@googlemail.com'
AND status <> '1')
```

, recursive_date_cte

AS

```
(SELECT dc1.*
    , 'sort_level' = 1
FROM date_cte dc1
WHERE sequential_order = 1
UNION
SELECT dc1.*
    , 'sort_level' = CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, dc1.date, dc2.date) <= 10 THEN sort_level
        ELSE sort_level + 1 END
LEFT JOIN date_cte dc2
    ON dc1.sequential_order = dc2.sequential_order - 1
WHERE dc1.sequential_order > 1)
```

SELECT *

FROM recursive_date_cte

ORDER BY sort_level ASC

```
, priority DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

just change the order or the colums in the order statement

```
SELECT * FROM converts WHERE email='myemail@googlemail.com' AND status!='1' ORDER BY priority DESC, date ASC
```

Comment: Date has to always be before priority but priority just needs more authority when some dates gets close to each within 10 minutes :)

Comment: The responder didn't seem to understand the question.  However, I definately like the responders picture of Wall-e.  :P

Comment: yeah, that was my issue, after I replied, I paid more attention and saw that the question was other. anyway sometime some questions are soooo obvious that I thought that this was one of them